# Jmeter pass parameters to ant

Tags: ant, jmeter

please, advice how to pass params(variable/property) from jmeter to ant. I need to pass JMeterThread.last_sample_ok result to ant target with mail tasks

If JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true send mail with success message
else 
 send mail with error message

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 ways:

1. Harder: write `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` variable value into a file using i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) and later on in Ant build script read the value using [LoadFile Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html)
2. Easier: instead of passing value to Ant just send an email from JMeter using [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and  [SMTP Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) combination.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, seems I always can count on you for solutions :). I took the first way with saving variable to external file via BeanShell script and load it back in ant with 

 <target name="doSendMail">
  
   <property file="../execResult.property"/>
  
  <condition property="sendError">
   <equals arg1="${noExecFailures}" arg2="false"/>
  </condition>  
  <condition property="sendOk">
   <equals arg1="${noExecFailures}" arg2="true"/>
  </condition>
 </target>